# change textSize with different language locale

Tags: android, eclipse

I have added spanish and french to my app but some of the wording is longer in spanish then english. how can i change the textsize when the values-es/string.xml file is accessed

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `dimens.xml` resource file for this purpose. In your case you'll probably want to create a file called `res/values-es/dimens.xml`, and possibly also a `-fr` version. You can specifify the default values in `res/values/dimens.xml` (or `res/values-en/dimens.xml`, if you want to be more specific).

Example grabbed from the [More Resource Types section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) on developer.android.com:

**dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Apply in xml**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

**Or in code**

```
float fontSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.font_size);
```

There are also solutions here on SO that use a iterative/recursive process to shrink the text size of a TextView to 'fit' in its bounding box (using a custom view), but I'd say above is a more robust approach, especially if you're considering adding more languages in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The above explanations are correct, but they don't fully explain how to do it.

When you open your project in Android Studio, then it automatically shows this project in the "**Android**" mode.  You need to click on the "Android" tab in the top, left corner of Android Studio and select "**Project**".  Then you need to go into "**app>src>main>res**".  Then you need to **right-click** on the "**res**" folder and from the menu that comes up, select "**New>Android resource directory**".  A dialogue will come up, and for Directory name: type in **values-es** and click **OK**.

This will create a folder for all Spanish Locale values.  And then you can **right-click** on this **values-es** folder to create **dimens.xml**, **string.xml**, **color.xml**, ...etc. files that will be used whenever Spanish Locale is selected in the phone.

If you've already created a string.xml file for Spanish Locale through the graphical user interface, then the values-es folder with string.xml file will already be in the Project, when you go there.  And in this case, you just need to **right-click** on the **values-es** folder to create the **dimens.xml** file there for Spanish Locale.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify a different layout file in layout-es. That way when Android pulls from values-es/string.xml, it'll load the different layout-es/yourfile.xml. That layout file can then specify a theme, style, or text size on the views.